# Erro ao dar nome para constraint do tipo check

Tags: sql, oracle

Olá, desculpa se a minha dúvida for muito trivial ou se ficar faltando alguma informação importante, mas estou tentando criar uma constraint do tipo check dando um nome específico pra ela, porém dá o seguinte erro:

```
ORA-00906: parêntese esquerdo não encontrado
00906. 00000 -  "missing left parenthesis"
```

Se eu simplesmente criar essa constraint sem dar um nome e deixar essa tarefa a cargo do próprio sistema, a instrução roda sem problemas.
Já procurei nos fóruns, mas não encontrei a resposta pra minha dúvida, pois os problemas relacionados ao erro acima estão todos voltados a instruções de buscas.

Sabem explicar o porquê do código acima dar erro? E como eu poderia fazer ele funcionar? Desde já, obrigado!

O código que dá erro é esse:

```
ALTER TABLE instalacao_periferico ADD CHECK chk_hora_desinstalacao 
(dt_hora_desinst_perif >= dt_hora_inst_perif);
```

O código que não dá erro é esse:

```
ALTER TABLE instalacao_periferico ADD CHECK (dt_hora_desinst_perif >= 
dt_hora_inst_perif);
```

Comment: O nome da constraint vem antes , exemplos em http://dba-oracle.com/t_alter_table_add_constraint_syntax_example.htm

Comment: Obrigado @Motta, no exemplo que eu dei, rodei o seguinte código e funcionou:


`ALTER TABLE instalacao_periferico ADD CONSTRAINT chk_hora_desinstalacao CHECK (dt_hora_desinst_perif >= dt_hora_inst_perif);`